Maximum board size for mating with a non-royal king
A fun mating problem for a change, for my chess kiddies: White has two kings, one is an "erlking" (as the problemists call it), moving like a king but doesn't have to care about checks and can be captured (as in losing chess).
Problem with mating K+E vs. K: The black king can try to run for the hills, and, so to say, is doubly as fast since both kings must come running after. What is the maximum board size for this mate (if at all)?

Are we assuming the board size is square?
On narrow rectangular boards the K+E easily win,
but we can still ask for the inclusion-maximal rectangles
on which the K+E have a forced mate.

Yes, the board is square, but feel free to generalize. (A related setup which might be easier to handle: Infinite one-edged board, bKa1, where must K+E stand to be able to box the bK in?)
